# вывести auto в конструкторе класса

Tags: c++, c++17

Я пытаюсь вывести тип поля класса в конструкторе следующим образом:

```
#include <tuple>

template <size_t k>

struct A {
   int val = k;

   void increment() { val++; }
};

class Container {
   auto data;

public:
   Container() : data(std::make_tuple(A<1>{}, A<2>{}, A<3>{})){ }

   void incrementAll() {
      std::apply([](auto... args){ (args.increment(), ...); }, data);
   }
};

int main() {
    Container c;

    c.incrementAll();
    return 0;
}
```

при попытке скомпилировать это с помощью GCC 7.2.0 получаю ошибку вида:

> ```
> error: non-static data member declared with placeholder auto
> ```

Инициальзировать поле data как `constexpr static` нельзя, т.к. кортеж изменяемый.

Comment: В чём проблема указать нужный тип `std::tuple`? `auto` в таких случаях язык не позволяет, т.к. может быть несколько мест инициализации члена класса.

Comment: И? Что там делает `auto` и зачем оно вам там понадобилось?

Comment: auto чтобы не прописывать std::tuple. Это не тот случай когда тип меняется и логично предположить что должен быть способ это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Практически, вы пытаетесь определить тип члена `data`  во время выполнения. Но размер типа должен быть известен во время компиляции, потому и во время компиляции должны быть известны типы его членов. Следовательно  ваша попытка  является ошибкой, тогда как вы смогли бы просто указать  его конкретный тип.  И, как замечание: метод  `incrementAll` не имеет никаких аргументов и не является шаблонным, поэтому он не может знать какие аргументы принимает лямбда. Так что тут тоже вы изрядно все запутали

Comment: Метод `incrementAll` может не принимать никаких параметров и не быть шаблонным: (пример) `[]<typename ...Ts>(Ts&& ...args) { (std::cout << .. << args) << '\n';  }`.

Comment: ваш пример не имеет никакого отношения с тем, что есть в вопросе

Comment: Я сейчас говорю о том, что написали Вы: метод  incrementAll не имеет **никаких аргументов и не является шаблонным, поэтому он не может знать какие аргументы принимает лямбда**. При чем здесь метод `incrementAll`?

Comment: насчёт метода incrementAll(): вы знаете более деликатный способ обойти кортеж и вызвать функцию increment?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если Вам не сложно - укажите на ошибку в приведенном мною примере. Пример: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TkDPrJ7pqFJoUvNt

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, **Если вы считаете, что функция в вопросе написана правильно** - повторяю, мои комментарии касаются исключительно Вашего ответа, а именно, я утверждаю, что не нужно изменять сигнатуру ф-ии `incrementAll` для того чтобы передать в лямбду tuple.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/318236/

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, на что именно в данной статье я должен обратить внимание? Если Вас это не затруднит, дайте ответ самостоятельно.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ссылка на пример в комментарии выше. В чем заключается ошибка?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, тем не менее, в начале сообщения упомянуто мое имя.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, с тех самых, когда люди научились признавать свои ошибки и перестали удалять комментарии. Извините, дискутировать с Вами я более не намерен.